# How to adjust space between legend markers and labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I want to adjust space between legend markers and labels. Sometime the space is too much as default. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[`legend()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) has a kwarg in called `handletextpad` which will do what you are looking for. By default, this is set to 0.8. From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend):

> `handletextpad` : float or None
>
> The pad between the legend handle and text. Measured in font-size
>   units.
>
> Default is None which will take the value from the
>   `legend.handletextpad` `rcParam`.

So when you call `legend`, add that kwarg, and experiment with the value. Something like:

```
ax.legend(handletextpad=0.1)
```

Consider the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax1.plot(range(5), 'ro', label='handletextpad=0.8')
ax2.plot(range(5), 'bo', label='handletextpad=0.1')

ax1.legend()
ax2.legend(handletextpad=0.1)

plt.show()
```

[image]